# Fundamental theorem of calculus corollary

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

May someone supply a proof to the following lemma:

If $ f $ is continuous on an open interval I and $ b $  is any point in I, then at each point in I $$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \int _x ^b f(t) dt =-f(x)$$

Comment: Shorter way than what way?

Comment: Than the ordinary one

Comment: Could you please provide a link or outline of "the ordinary one?" It is very vague as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\;f\;$ is continuous in $\;I\;$ it has there a primitive $\;F\;$ , so

$$\forall\, b,x\in I\;,\;\;\int_x^bf(t)dt=F(b)-F(x)\implies$$

$$\frac d{dx}\int_x^b f(t)dx=\frac d{dx}\left(F(b)-F(x)\right)=-F'(x)=-f(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Using chain rule in the fundamental calculus theorem you get something like this:
$$\frac{d}{dx}{\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt} = f(b(x)) \cdot b'(x) - f(a(x)) \cdot a'(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(\int_x^a f)'=\big((\int_p^af)- (\int_p^xf)\big)'=-f.$$